# Указатель на метод класса и его подклассов без шаблонов

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Есть функция, которая принимает указатель на метод класса Object

```
void f(void(Object::*_function)(int))
{
   //...
}
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы она принимала не только методы самого Object, но и его подклассов, не используя шаблонов ?

Comment: `_function` виртуальная?

Comment: нет, не виртуальная

Comment: Вызов метода дочернего класса на объект базового класса - бессмыслица. В базовом классе нет таких переменных какие использует дочерний метод . Вы по-сути будете *"резать по живому, с кровью"*.

Comment: увы но вряд ли это возможно без sfinae, а в чем проблема использовать шаблоны?

Comment: я планировал сделать f() виртуальным методом одного класса, но шаблонные функции не могут быть виртуальными

Answer (score 1):

Можно скастовать указатель на метод потомка к нужному типу:

```
f(static_cast<void(Object::*)(int)>(&Derived::foo));
```

Естественно, когда будете вызывать метод через этот указатель, ссылка/указатель на `Object`, которые будут стоять слева от `.*`/`->*`, должны указывать на дочерний класс, а то будет неопределенное поведение.